# Moment isBetween with inclusion parameter do not work

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using momentjs.

I want to show a value if a date is between two date (and include those 2 dates)

following moment [Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

```
moment('2019/09/02').isBetween(
  '1900/01/01',
  '2019/09/02',
  '[]'
)
```

Why is this returning false ? it should return true as today is included in today.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check again the doc.

The third param is the granularity and the fourth param is the interval.

so in your case, it should be

```
moment('2019/09/02').isBetween(
  '1900/01/01',
  '2019/09/02',
  null, // can be year, month .... the granularity of your comaprison
  '[]'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this trick.

```
moment('2019/09/02).isBetween('1900/01/01', '2019/09/02 23:59:59');
```